# How to create skills multi-select feild in my own flutter app like linkedin skills field

Tags: flutter, multi-select

I want to use some public api to fetch skills can you suggest. Want to create a multi select dropdown for selecting skills

Researched in google and rapid Api but can't find any option also some videos in youtube but can't find

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use [multi_dropdown](https://pub.dev/packages/multi_dropdown) for selecting multiple options for filtering data or picking various preferences.